# sizeinbase for mpz_class in GNU GMP

Tags: c++, gmp

In C we have `mpz_t` and we can access the size in a `base` by

```
size_t mpz_sizeinbase (const mpz_t op, int base)
```

In mpz_class, I've tried

```
counter.sizeinbase(2);
```

that didn't work.

```
error: ‘mpz_class {aka class __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>}’ has no member named ‘sizeinbase’
      size_t size = (counter.sizeinbase(2) + CHAR_BIT-1) / CHAR_BIT;
```

I need to use mpz_class to simplify the code for unordered_map

is there a similar function for mpz_class or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `get_mpz_t` method to access the wrapped `mpz_t` value.

```
mpz_class x = ...;
size_t xbits = mpz_sizeinbase(x.get_mpz_t(), 2);
```

At least this works in MPIR, I assume it works in GMP as well.